# Вечная ошибка по выдаче почт [C#]

Tags: c#, парсер, requests

пытаюсь сделать парсер коммерческих почт с ютуба на C#, передаю все нужные параметры, но всё время высвечивается ошибка того, что я превысил лимит просмотра коммерческих почт(с одного аккаунта, в день, можно смотреть 5 таких почт, если я не ошибаюсь в количестве), хотя я вообще не превышаю этот запрос, а от силы делаю один такой запрос для того, чтобы найти нужные параметры в Postman(через него отправляю запросы к yt, чтобы потом перевести в C# код). Подскажите, в чём может быть ошибка?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот и сама ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `можно смотреть 5 таких почт, если я не ошибаюсь в количестве` - получается что ошибаетесь. Гляньте доки

Comment: @Aarnihauta не могу найти ничего тоб этом в доке, если не сложно, киньте линк